Ограничить вход по группе пользователя через pam
Тут скорее 2 вопроса по PAM:
Как дать привилегию процессу сервера подключаться к pam?
Хочу чтоб процесс работал от своего пользователя, а не от рута. Сейчас сделал подпроцесс со стики битом. Но при обновлении это слетит.
Поэкспериментировать можно с echo user password | /usr/lib/squid/basic_pam_auth. От рута - работает, от пользователя - нет.
Как сделать чтоб PAM сервис проверял группу пользователя?
Например создаем /etc/pam.d/myservice
@include common-auth
@include common-account

Проверяем - ок
echo user password | /usr/lib/squid/basic_pam_auth -n myservice


По второй части можно через файл со списком групп:
auth required pam_listfile.so onerr=fail item=group sense=allow file=/etc/myservice/groups.allowed

